# OSX terminal running a command in a single window

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, console

I use my OS X machine to administer a couple of servers and like to keep open terminal.app to do this. I have my profile so i get a few tabs open as i open the terminal.app, is it possible to assign to each tab a different theme and different starting command so that i can automatically SSH to each of the boxes as i run terminal.app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used Terminal.app since I discovered [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/), which is free. It has customisable profiles and a bookmarks feature that might really help with what you need. Check it out...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.  In `"Terminal > Preferences > Settings"`, create a setting for each connection.  In each of these, configure the appearance of the window (color scheme, etc) and specify the connection with `"Shell > Startup > Run command"`.
[image]

After you have created these settings, open whatever mix of windows and tabs that you want.  You do this by using the `"File > New Window"` and `"File > New Tab"` and selecting the appropriate settings.  Then save your window settings with `"Window > Save Windows as Group..."`.

When you open this Window group, it will run the command that you specified in the Settings' startup commands, re-establishing those connections.  You can open Window Groups from the `"Window > Open Window Group"`, or configure one to start automatically in `"Preferences > Startup"`.

Answer (score 2):

another options is using screen and put the right options in your .screenrc.
it has everything you need: tabs, starting command, naming tabs .....
when you start screen, it reads your .screenrc file and then starts all commands you have configured in, like opening different tabs, starting few applications and many more ...
the reason why i use screen is i can use it on almost every *nix whithout changing a single line of my .screenrc.
don't hesitate to message me if you want a .screenrc file example.
(new user here so i can'g post hyperlinks right now :( )